# Jolt - Conditional update LHS value

Tags: jolt

I basically have 2 different condition which can impact the value of a key in the output.
I have following input:

```json
{
  "state": "PRESENT",
  "sample": {
    "type": "OP"
  }
}
```

I have following spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "state": {
        "PRESENT": {
          "#ANSWER1": "answer"
        },
        "*": {
          "$": "answer"
        }
      },
      "sample":{
        "type":{
          "OP":{
            "#ANSWER2": "answer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Now if you see that both the conditions are true, the final output is as following. Both the values come in form of an array

```json
{
  "answer" : [ "ANSWER1", "ANSWER2" ]
}
```

But I am looking for an output based on the second condition. Basically override the existing value in "answer" attribute:

```json
{
  "answer" : "ANSWER2"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add one more **shift** transformation

```json
{
  "operation": "shift",
  "spec": {
    "*": { "1": { "@": "&2" } }
  }
}
```

to the existing specification in order to pick the second(the element with the index `1`) element.

If picking the left element of the array was the case, then cardinality **transformation** might be preferred to use

```json
{
  "operation": "cardinality",
  "spec": {
    "*": "ONE"
  }
}
```